# Why can't I use a parameter string to name my button?

Tags: c#, .net, parameters, abstract

I'm creating a lot of buttons on the back end so I figured it would be intelligent to abstract it out to cut down on lines of code. When I try to do this though, it gives me an error saying "A local or parameter named "buttonName" cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter". Am I missing something here? I thought this was the exact reason to use a parameter in this situation.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do.

turn this

```
Button buttonDetailsEdit = new Button();
buttonDetailsEdit.ID = "ButtonDetailsEdit";
buttonDetailsEdit.Text = "Edit";
buttonDetailsEdit.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
buttonDetailsEdit.Click += new EventHandler(EditCall);
PlaceHolderDetailsContent.Controls.Add(buttonDetailsEdit);

Button buttonDetailsBack = new Button();
buttonDetailsBack.ID = "ButtonDetailsBack";
buttonDetailsBack.Text = "Back to List";
buttonDetailsBack.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
buttonDetailsBack.Click += new EventHandler(IndexCall);
PlaceHolderDetailsContent.Controls.Add(buttonDetailsBack);
```

Into this (with a method call in place of the old code)

```
void CreateButton(string buttonName, string buttonIDText, string buttonText, PlaceHolder PlaceHolderName, string methodCall)
{
    Button buttonName = new Button();
    buttonName.ID = buttonIDText;
    buttonName.Text = buttonText;
    buttonName.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
    buttonName.Click += new EventHandler(methodCall);
    PlaceHolderName.Controls.Add(buttonName);
}
```

the methodCall portion also throws an error here, I'm assuming due to "methodCall" not existing in this instance.

Comment: Look at the type of `IndexCall` in your working code...

Comment: "the methodCall portion also throws an error here" - so what's the error? The same error, or a different one?

Comment: Why have you called your `Button` local variable `buttonName` anyway? Surely `button` would be more appropriate, as well as avoiding the issue. It's unclear in what way the compiler error message is unclear here... it's telling you *exactly* what's wrong.

Comment: You're trying to declare a new variable of type `Button` called `buttonName` in a method where there is already a variable of type `string` called `buttonName`.  You can't do that.  If you don't need your buttons to be accessible by fields, your method can be made to work by changing `buttonName` to some other name that doesn't conflict with the parameter you're passing into the method.

Comment: Your parameter (string buttonName) is exactly the same name as your Button buttonName. It's a naming convention problem. Just change your parameter to string buttonname or _buttonName or btnName. as long as it is not buttonName.

Comment: Can't you make Button ButtonNew,, ButtonNew.ID= ButtonName. It fits your first example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't have two variables `string buttonName` and `Button buttonName` with the same name in the same scope.

Try to rename your button to, for example, `Button newButton`

Comment: your confusing the variable name with the `Name` property of the `Button` class.

Comment: Ah I understand now. Since it's already being declared in the parameter, I don't have to declare it inside the method, correct? So I can just drop the Button portion and keep the buttonName = new Button();

Comment: I believe your pre-edited answer was better. This will still require 2 lines, I think when calling it. One to declare the button and one to call it, right? So it should look something like this

Button buttonBack = new Button();

CreateButton(buttonBack, "buttonBackId", "Back To List", TBNewDescrip, IndexCall);

Answer (score 2):

You have declared a parameter named `buttonName`:

```
string buttonName
```

*And* you have declared a `Button` variable of the same name:

```
Button buttonName
```

You cannot have both. This is what the compiler is complaining about.

---

Now, *actually*, your issue seems to be that you want to use the *content* of the parameter as a local variable name. This is generally not possible - variable names must be known at compile time, not only at runtime.

Luckily, you do not actually need that - it does not matter what your local `Button` variable is called within your method, as that name will be lost when the method ends (actually, it will probably not even make it through compilation). The important part is that with each invocation of your method, a new `Button` *instance* will be created (and ultimately added to the list).

Therefore, simply rename your `Button` variable to `newButton` and drop the `buttonName` parameter because it isn't used any more.

Answer (score -1):

The variable name `buttonName` was reused and the type of `methodCall` was incorrect.  You need a delegate parameter to allow the selected function to be passed into the method.

```
void CreateButton(string buttonName, 
                  string buttonIDText, 
                  string buttonText, 
                  PlaceHolder placeHolder, 
                  EventHandler methodCall) // needed to fix your type
{
    var button = new Button(); //reused variable name
    button.ID = buttonIDText;
    button.Name = buttonName; //you missed assigning the button name
    button.Text = buttonText;
    button.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
    button.Click += methodCall; // you dont need to do new EventHandler
    placeHolder.Controls.Add(button);
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue or remove the error, nor does it explain anything.

Comment: this fixes his error as he is trying to pass a string as a delegate

Comment: @MatthewWhited: That is one of the errors in the code posted by the OP, but it is not the error they are asking about in the question primarily (as per the title).

Comment: and I didn't see that second error but it is now fixed...good to see the SO mafia is up for wrong down votes.

Comment: "the methodCall portion also throws an error here, I'm assuming due to "methodCall" not existing in this instance."

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure what was the correct type to send for a method.